# Custom keyboard shortcut for jupyter-notebook and jupyter-lab for moving line up/down

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sublimetext3, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Can we use sublime style keyboard shortcuts in jupyter-notebook and jupyter-lab cells ?

** Example Requirement:**
cmd shift up  moves the line up in jupyter cell

**NOTE:** 
 I am using jupyter-lab using conda environment.

My attempts:

1. In jupyter-lab I changed text editor to sublime, it works only in
   text editor, not in jupyter cells.
2. I followed this blog:
   http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-get-sublime-text-style-editing-in-the-ipythonjupyter-notebook/

   - placed the javascript at `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`
   - also tried at `~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/static/custom/custom.js`

cmd-shift-up/down selects line and above line, does not move them.

3. Installed extension
   https://github.com/ryantam626/jupyterlab_black

This also did not work in jupyter-cell.

## can we do like this (use sublime keymaps in jupyter cell) ?

http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-get-sublime-text-style-editing-in-the-ipythonjupyter-notebook/
[image]