# How to move line (not cell) up/down in jupyter notebook using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I move a line (or set of selected lines) down or up in jupyter notebook. Are there any shortcuts?
[image]
After moving line 3 one line up:
[image]
For example `ALT+UP` or `ALT+DOWN` is for up/down displacement that is used in **Eclipse** IDE.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453756/how-to-move-jupyter-notebook-cells-up-down-using-keyboard-shortcut) question discusses cell displacement.

Comment: Same question without answers: [Custom keyboard shortcut for jupyter-notebook and jupyter-lab for moving line up/down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55692324/7851470)

Comment: The easiest way really is to write a swap function for it, but I don't think that's what you're looking for anyway.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:**
By following [this tutorial](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-get-sublime-text-style-editing-in-the-ipythonjupyter-notebook/), I was able to enable all the sublime-text shortcuts (which includes the moving lines with Ctrl+Up/Ctrl/Down).

I then was able to furthermore, customize the shortcuts by editing the `sublime.js`

**Complete answer:**

1. Find your jupyter path with `jupyter --config-dir`
2. Add the following code to `<JUPYTER-PATH>/custom/custom.js`:

```py
require(["codemirror/keymap/sublime", "notebook/js/cell", "base/js/namespace"],
    function(sublime_keymap, cell, IPython) {
        // setTimeout(function(){ // uncomment line to fake race-condition
        cell.Cell.options_default.cm_config.keyMap = 'sublime';
        var cells = IPython.notebook.get_cells();
        for(var cl=0; cl< cells.length ; cl++){
            cells[cl].code_mirror.setOption('keyMap', 'sublime');
        }
 
        // }, 1000)// uncomment  line to fake race condition 
    } 
);
```

3. You need to find this `codemirror/keymap/sublime.js` (that is required in the code from point 2), for me, it was in `<MY-PYTHON-ENVIRONMENT>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/static/components/codemirror/keymap/sublime.js`
4. At the end of this file, you can edit the shortcuts, in the `keyMap.pcSublime` section of this file (if you have a PC).
5. For OP, the lines to edit would be: `swapLineUp` and `swapLineDown`

I did this with Ubuntu & sublime installed.

Answer (score 1):

Since jupyter works with code blocks you can use that shortcut between code blocks as

```
Ctrl + Shift + -
```

But this will only works between code cells not in the same code block. I don't think there is a built-in shortcut for that. For more shortcuts you can look here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/

Answer (score 1):

---

> You can select the line with mouse in jupyter notebook.       Drag it
> up or down before the line where you want to move it.       Press >
> button on keyboard while your text is still selected.
> This will bring the cursor to end of selected line,
> but before the text of line being replaced.      Press Enter.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a shortcut in Jupyter, however, you can [manage your own shorcuts](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html) Go to `Help` > `Edit keyboard Shortcuts` and start setting your commands.

There's some good info on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55397873/14325407) which will lead you to manage your profile's *notebook.json* file and so on.

Hope this was useful ;)

*Edit: typo*

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom shortcuts in Jupyter notebook
[Jupyter Shortcuts](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html)